# Javascript is not detectinng boolean false

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have one variable in my javascript file. Lets call that variable "isValid". Its value is false.
I have to check its value in if statement , like this:

```
if(!isValid){
//Do something
}
```

But its not at all going inside if statement. I have checked this by putting alert statement. Then I have used typeof() like this:

```
if(typeof(isValid) === false){
//Do something
}
```

But this is also not working. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: typeof returns a string ... without seeing actual code, who knows what you are actually setting `isValid` to ... `false != "false"` ... an intersting thing would be to `console.log(typeof isValid);` before the `if` test - you should get `boolean`

Comment: typeof isValid will return a string. Check if it is 'boolean' in your case. `0, '', null` also are falsy values.

Comment: to clarify, **if** isValid is indeed `false` ... `typeof isValid` will == the STRING `"boolean"`

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan - POSSIBLY boolean, since it is "truthy" by virtue of the first example, it could be anything that isn't "falsey"

Comment: Is there any other way to check false condition without typeof?

Comment: I don't understand. why `if` it's not good enough?

Comment: one would NEVER use `typeof` to check boolean condition ... as we can't see HOW you've set "isValid", we can only speculate

Comment: @ShubhangiGarg `if (isValid === false) then ..`

Comment: Try a more verbose test to see, what exactly you are dealing with: `if (typeof (isValid) !== 'boolean') {
  alert(typeof (isValid) + ' is not boolean');
}
if (isValid !== true) {
  alert('isValid is false');
} else {
  alert('isValid is true');
}`

Comment: `I have one variable in my javascript file. Lets call that variable "isValid". Its value is false` ... of these three statements, the third is clearly **wrong** as demonstrated by your code ... it's NOT false, nor is it "falsey", it is either true, or "truthy" ... do you understand what is "truthy" and "falsey"

Comment: Too little information! First of all you should make sure that isValid is false. Use `console.log(isValid)`

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: I printed the output from typeof(isValid). It is giving string instead of boolean :(

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this : 
if variable contains false just give condition 
value == 'false'

```
var value = "false"; //string

if (value=='false')
{
    console.log("this is false")
}
else
{
   .... some code
}

value = false; //now your variable is a boolean
if(value === false)
{
    return "something";
}
else
{
    ..... some code
}
```

// print : this is false

Comment: no .. `false` is not the same as `'false'` ... I think you are adding to the confusion

Comment: false == 'false' => false

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually, I was getting the value of variable from my java bean class. When I check the type of isValid variable by using typeof method, it shown string. So I put false in quotes, n it worked. Thank you